Unable to install msal-react in React 19. It fails with below error of peer dependency
Could not resolve dependency:
peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0 || ^18.0" from @azure/msal-react@2.2.0

you didn't attach the screenshot.

but, please see: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

updated the question with the error message

@azure/msal-react@2.2.0 doesn't list React 19 as a peer dependency, so the install error fits. You can either force install it, downgrade to a version of React that is compatible, or search for another library that supports React 19. In the meantime I suggest you file an issue with the maintainers.
